# How to move from Java to Kotlin for web security configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm trying to port my SpringBoot 3.0.5 web security configuration for a simple program from Java to Kotlin.

I have the following web security configuration in Java:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain secretPageAuthentication(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/secretPage")
                .authenticated().and().oauth2Login();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The goal is that users should only be able to access `/secretPage` after authenticating with oauth2, but any other pages otherwise. This works as intended.

I've tried rewriting the class in Kotlin as follows:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    open fun customerTerminalAuthentication(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/secretPage")
            .authenticated().and().oauth2Login()
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, but the oauth2 restriction is applied to all routes, not just "/secretPage".

How can I write a security configuration for the desired behaviour in Kotlin?

Comment: It looks to me as if the Kotlin version should compile to just about the same as the Java version (except for the different method name, and the fact that the Kotlin class isn't open (unless you're using a Maven/Gradle plugin which makes Spring-related things open)). (You could confirm that by decompiling the resulting bytecode if you wanted.) If those minor differences don't explain what you're seeing, could there be some other difference in code elsewhere, or in how you're running it?

Comment: it seems to be more a spring boot configuration issue than a kotlin issue.